# how to continuosly change label position with position of uislider

Tags: ios, uislider

i am making an app in which i am creating UIslider programmaticaly and i am changing label value according to the value of uislider,now i want that While sliding, the value should slide aswell as showing in figure below.How it can be done. For good explanation i am attaching a screen shot so u people can better understand it.[image: i want this type of behaviour]

below is my code:

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(150, 230, 300.0, 10.0);
    radius = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [radius addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [radius setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    radius.minimumValue = 10.0;
    radius.maximumValue = 300.0;
    radius.continuous = YES;
    radius.value = 10.0;

    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    radius.transform = trans;
    //self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 10];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView_];
    [self.view insertSubview:radius aboveSubview:self.mapView_];
}
-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{
    _SliderDefaultValue=radius.value;
    NSLog (@"the slider value ==%f",_SliderDefaultValue);



    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", _SliderDefaultValue];
}
```

thanx in advance

Comment: if u need third party for custom uislider

Comment: third party means ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [tutorial](http://www.getappninja.com/blog/how-to-make-a-custom-uislider) will resolve your issue

Comment: but how can i set my uislide class programmaticaly ??? as i am doing it programmaticaly not drag and drop